# Create Construct Function Magento2

Tags: magento2

i want to create class construct function in this model this is payment model  PaymentMethod extends `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` i try but getting an error what wrong I am doing.

```
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentMethodInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment;
use Cryozonic\StripePayments\Helper\Logger;

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
        );
        $this->_paymentData = $paymentData;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->initializeData($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` then your `__construct` function should have followed below classes parameters

```
     \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    Logger $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = [],
    DirectoryHelper $directory = null
```

**So, your `__construct` have minimum below code**

```
    <?php

namespace {YourNameSpace};

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;
use Cryozonic\StripePayments\Helper\Logger;

class {YourClass} extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = [],
        DirectoryHelper $directory = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $paymentData,
            $scopeConfig,
            $logger,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data,
            $directory
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: share your code

Comment: see my question i updated

Comment: see my code? need help

Comment: Answer updated  and `{YourNameSpace}`  & `{YourClass}` with your  namespace & class repectively.

Comment: sir it obviosu class namese already ther

Comment: i did not mentioned here but in my code its

Comment: not working still

Comment: currently my checkout page just loading with white page afte adding your code

Comment: your solution worked now the issue is that i want to object manager now i am adding in coustruct like this

Comment: getting error public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
   \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,.

Comment: better to post your whole code so that amit can check and help you better